# Почему не подключаются изображения не github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не подключаются изображения на странице Github pages, уже много чего перепробовал.
Вот репозиторий: https://github.com/Danvarius/project-x
Вот ссылка на Github Pages: https://danvarius.github.io/project-x/
[image: скрин кода]

Comment: Потому что изображения у вас фактически имеют url вида `https://danvarius.github.io/project-x/image/AEG.png`, а вы на них ссылаетесь по url вида `https://danvarius.github.io/image/AEG.png` (url начинающийся со слеша `/image/AEG.png` - это url относительно корня сайта)

Comment: @insolor спасибо большое вам, очень благодарен за помощь)